# Free IDE for enterprise use to program R - any tips?

Tags: r

I recently started working at a company that would benefit from my R programming skills, however, I can't use R-studio because the enterprise edition isn't free. I also gave Jupyter Notebook a shot, but in order to use Jupyter, I would need Anaconda Navigator which also isn't free for enterprises.

If anyone knows of a IDE that is user-friendly and completely free for the use of R, please let me know! I am simply trying to show my company that R would be useful before buying an enterprise edition. All tips appreciated.

I already read multiple posts, but none seem to have a good solution: [IDE alternatives for R programming (RStudio, IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, Visual Studio)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5345/ide-alternatives-for-r-programming-rstudio-intellij-idea-eclipse-visual-stud/28853#28853)

Comment: You don't need Anaconda Navigator to run jupyter notebooks.

Comment: @noe you're completey right, I just did not have R downloaded on this computer. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: I'm not competent for legal stuff, but I would think rstudio can be used in a company. Of course there's no support for the free version, and probably you can't commercialize any product based on rstudio. But my understanding is that just using it as an IDE is ok.